# Hisense Vidaa file transfer from android and iPhone to Smart TV

Tags: usb, bluetooth

My Hisense Vidaa TV is telling me that it is a Linux OS based system and want's me to continuously update my browser from google chrome which I've just used as the default browser, and in my settings on both iPhone 6s, and Vivo 2028 Y11s the Hisense OS systems show up as Linux, I don't know how to identify which version of Linux it is when google prompts me to start the update it just says here's additional information for Linux systems using either 32bit/64bit Debian or Ubuntu
I was able to send my google photos and other additional settings upon first time using the TV but now I can't find the way to go about it again and using screencasting as well as it drops out after 30secs/1min using the android settings for Bluetooth casting and direct USB and wi-fi wireless connectivity